# how to use Rxjava with room and use mvvm with LiveData //How do I switch usage from executorService to rxjava?

Tags: java, android, android-room, dagger-hilt, rx-java3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WByuO.png)

What is the best approach to replace the use of **`executorService`** with RxJava in a repository class that is used with **`ViewModel`** and **`LiveData`** in an Android app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.